# Display a map with clickable countries

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I need to create a map of countries that can be any shape next to each other in my JavaFX application. I need to be able to click on an individual country, which will result in a action.

Should I create buttons which represent each country? I have about 30 countries so this may not be very efficient, and it won't allow much customisation (such as placing markers on the map inside the country boundaries).

What is the right component to use in my application?

Comment: Hello Lio, unfortunately your question is too broad for Stack Overflow. This platform works best with actual coding problems. Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1288408)

Comment: Its not a question i guess, but i just need ideas as I am very new to coding, really just to help me get started as I've been struggling on this for awhile. I apologise for being to broad.

Comment: No problem. You didn't ask a bad question, it's just not a good fit for this site. Asking for ideas would be off-topic because it would lead to opinionated answers. It would be best to ask this question somewhere else and come back when you tried to implement a solution and run into problems. In its current form your question will likely be closed and might attract more downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already mentioned the solution in your question. Just use a Shape. In your case a simple Polygon for each country would be ok. In JavaFX you cannot only click on buttons. You can also click on any shape and detect that and then act accordingly. Just add the appropriate event handler to each shape.

Comment: thank you so much, I will definitely do that. The only thing is i would need to create about 30 different shapes and click actions, that seems to be very inefficient and messy. Is their a way to make it such they do not take as much space?

Comment: The size should not really be a  problem. Maybe this is useful for you too. https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/WorldMapView.html

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.